# Erro do analisador

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

vocês já se depararam com esse tipo de problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este erro esta começou a acontecer em um projeto que já esta em fase final. Para testar o ambiente criei um projeto simples e ao executar o erro ocorre também.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903898/fixing-syntax-error-in-global-asax

Comment: Renomeou algum arquivo recentemente?

Comment: Gabriel, acredito que sim

Comment: É bem provável que algumas referências a essa alteração não tenha sido alterada. Faz o seguinte, dê um rollback para uma versão anterior a esse renomeio e veja se soluciona temporariamente.

Comment: @GabrielColetta fiz os testes aqui e o problema não é relacionado a isso, estou tentando entender a solução que o CaiqueRomero mandou. Acredito que o problema seja no ambiente e não no projeto em si, porque qualquer projeto que eu crio do zero, esse problema acontece.